# Logo above navigation bar

Tags: html, css

It's my first time making site, what should I do to have my site logo above the navigation bar? And if someone could correct my code and tell my what I did wrong.

www.codepen.io/anon/pen/VaPKaK

Comment: The logo shows just fine

Comment: There is no logo now. I want to  place it above navigation bar something like this. example: https://www.thoughtfarmer.com/imagethumb/197871900000/9231/0x0/False/main%20nav.png And i just don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a space between "home" and style in your image tag

It's a bit confusing what you're asking, would you like your logo image to literally appear above your navigation? if so the don't put the image tag in an a list tag

So instead of:

```html
<li id="home"><a class="active" href="#home"><img src="home.png" alt="Home"style="width:20px;height:20px;"></a></li>
  <li id="news"><a href="#news">Blog</a></li>
```

TRY

```html
<a class="active" href="#home"><img src="home.png" alt="Home" style="width:20px;height:20px;"></a>
  <li id="news"><a href="#news">Blog</a></li>
```

Also, try not to add styles to your html. Put them in your CSS. It makes it all much easier to read.

Here is the edited [Codepen](http://codepen.io/E-nathan/pen/pyREPG) with all those edits and the logo is above the Navigation.
Hope that helps!!

Comment: "There is no logo now. I want to place it above navigation bar something like this. example: thoughtfarmer.com/imagethumb/197871900000/9231/0x0/False/… And i just don't know how" home.png is just a main page button.

Comment: I've edited my answer with the a link to the codepen I edited for you. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: thanks man! one more thing how can i change color only above my navigation bar?

Comment: aaand it doesn't work it shows like this http://puu.sh/nJgch/6ebd7728f1.jpg i think it need to be a part of navigation bar becouse i have my navigation bar made always on top when scrolling page down

Comment: Okay so I've edited the [link](http://codepen.io/E-nathan/pen/pyREPG) again to show how everything can be manipulated with the css to either remain fixed when scrolling and not fixed (in this case the <h1>)
I wrapped everything in from your logo to the end of your navigation in a div and set it's position as fixed. Then I added an H1 with a margin above it to show you how it works when you scroll.
Has that helped?